# Does my App still update Firestore when I minimise it?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a code whereby it runs a for loop upon pressing a button, which will in turn update Firestore for every time the loop repeats.

On my iOS simulator, when I lock the simulator or minimise the app, Firestore still updates. However, on my physical device, whenever I minimise the app Firestore stops updating and only resumes when I re enter the app.

I am afraid that users might not have their data fully updated to Firestore before they navigate away from the app or page, and also do not want to hold users to the page with a progress bar forcing them to wait on the page.

Is there a solution to this? Or is the only way to implement a spinner that spins until the for loop is finished?

If so, how do I ensure that the method is complete before I end the spinner? As my method containing the for loop is Async, it doesnt wait for Firestore to finish updating before it toggles my spinner off.

Comment: quick question, are you using Firestore with Firebase or Firestore with GCP?

Comment: I am using Firestore with Firebase